# $_GET value does not work inside if condition

Tags: php, json, get

I am parsing the json data where id is used as condition to parse the data but it does not work inside the if condition

```
 <?php

    if(isset( $_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['city']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $city=$_GET['city'];

}

    $json = file_get_contents('../jsonfile/cities/'.$city.'.json')/deals.json?tsToken=US_AFF_0_201590_221707_0
    $json_string = json_decode($json);


    foreach($json_string->deals as $mydata)

    {

    if($mydata->id == $id) //does not work 
            {
            foreach($mydata->options[0]->details as $option)
            { 
                 echo  $option->description;
        }
```

$id is echo fine but it does not work inside the if condition please help me out..... :)

Comment: does it work outside?

Comment: By the transitive property, one would deduce that `$a` must not equal `$id`, and the mistake in your logic is that somehow it should.

Comment: yes it works fine outside

Comment: First check your values $mydata->id and  $id, print them by individually. I think values are not matching up.
And one more thing, you wrote for '$a' its works, so whats the $a in your case?

Comment: dear lc $a is used only for check purpose

Comment: user3540050 i printed both $mydata->id and $id both printed same value

Comment: You also have a very interesting division operation going on on line 10. I'm surprised your code gets as far as the if-statement you're referring to...can you reduce your code to the *smallest possible* sample of code that reproduces this error, and include *all* relevant details. As it stands, there is nothing anyone can do to help you debug this.

Answer (score 0):

// try this

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$a = '{"a":1,"b":"test String"}';
$b = json_decode($a,true);
print_r($b);
```

True when passed with json_decode returns an array and u can make use of it to compare.

Answer (score 0):

If $json_string->deals is an array you may want to try changing your if condition to: if($mydata['id'] == $id).

Although json_decode returns an object as a container not all of the stuff inside it will necessarily be object type too.